# How to write Photoshop action manager code like this?

Tags: javascript, photoshop

I get some code from https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1536677, this can get layer's bounds

```
function getLBounds(){
  var ref = new ActionReference();
  ref.putEnumerated( charIDToTypeID("Lyr ") , charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" ), charIDToTypeID( "Trgt" ) );
  desc1 = executeActionGet(ref);
  desc1 = desc1.getObjectValue(stringIDToTypeID('bounds'));
  desc1Top = desc1.getUnitDoubleValue(stringIDToTypeID('top'));
  desc1Bottom = desc1.getUnitDoubleValue(stringIDToTypeID('bottom'));
  desc1Left = desc1.getUnitDoubleValue(stringIDToTypeID('left'));
  desc1Right = desc1.getUnitDoubleValue(stringIDToTypeID('right'));
  rObj = {top:desc1Top, left:desc1Left, bottom:desc1Bottom, right:desc1Right};
  return rObj;
}
```

I want to know how to write or use ScriptListener.8li to generate this, I can use ScriptListener.8li to do some transform,etc.But I do not know how to get information.many thanks!

```
// =======================================================
var idTrnf = charIDToTypeID( "Trnf" );
var desc2 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idFTcs = charIDToTypeID( "FTcs" );
var idQCSt = charIDToTypeID( "QCSt" );
var idQcsa = charIDToTypeID( "Qcsa" );
desc2.putEnumerated( idFTcs, idQCSt, idQcsa );

var idOfst = charIDToTypeID( "Ofst" );
var desc3 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idHrzn = charIDToTypeID( "Hrzn" );
var idPxl = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
desc3.putUnitDouble( idHrzn, idPxl, 0.000000 );
var idVrtc = charIDToTypeID( "Vrtc" );
var idPxl = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
desc3.putUnitDouble( idVrtc, idPxl, 0.013677 );

var idOfst = charIDToTypeID( "Ofst" );
desc2.putObject( idOfst, idOfst, desc3 );
var idWdth = charIDToTypeID( "Wdth" );
var idPrc = charIDToTypeID( "#Prc" );
desc2.putUnitDouble( idWdth, idPrc, 86.486860 );
var idHght = charIDToTypeID( "Hght" );
var idPrc = charIDToTypeID( "#Prc" );
desc2.putUnitDouble( idHght, idPrc, -88.215838 );

var idSkew = charIDToTypeID( "Skew" );
var desc4 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idHrzn = charIDToTypeID( "Hrzn" );
var idAng = charIDToTypeID( "#Ang" );
desc4.putUnitDouble( idHrzn, idAng, 0.033079 );
var idVrtc = charIDToTypeID( "Vrtc" );
var idAng = charIDToTypeID( "#Ang" );
desc4.putUnitDouble( idVrtc, idAng, 0.000000 );

var idPnt = charIDToTypeID( "Pnt " );
desc2.putObject( idSkew, idPnt, desc4 );
var idAngl = charIDToTypeID( "Angl" );
var idAng = charIDToTypeID( "#Ang" );
desc2.putUnitDouble( idAngl, idAng, -170.957285 );
executeAction( idTrnf, desc2, DialogModes.NO );
```

PS:The last code is generated form ScriptListener.8li, I want to know how to generate the first function getLBounds.

Answer (score 0):

There is a list of the four letter script listener codes around. *"Trnf"* is transform, for instance. Google is your friend.

But sometimes it's easy to go over each command and look at each parameter in turn. I can see that your bit of code rotates and shrinks the image layer non-proportionally, adds a bit of skew and a teeny tiny bit of offset.

```
// =======================================================
var idTrnf = charIDToTypeID( "Trnf" );
var desc2 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idFTcs = charIDToTypeID( "FTcs" );
var idQCSt = charIDToTypeID( "QCSt" );
var idQcsa = charIDToTypeID( "Qcsa" );
desc2.putEnumerated( idFTcs, idQCSt, idQcsa );
var idOfst = charIDToTypeID( "Ofst" );
var desc3 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idHrzn = charIDToTypeID( "Hrzn" );
var idPxl = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
desc3.putUnitDouble( idHrzn, idPxl, 0.000000 ); // X transform offest amount in pixels
var idVrtc = charIDToTypeID( "Vrtc" );
var idPxl = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
desc3.putUnitDouble( idVrtc, idPxl, 0.013677 ); // Y transform offest amount in pixels
var idOfst = charIDToTypeID( "Ofst" );
desc2.putObject( idOfst, idOfst, desc3 );
var idWdth = charIDToTypeID( "Wdth" );
var idPrc = charIDToTypeID( "#Prc" );
desc2.putUnitDouble( idWdth, idPrc, 86.486860 ); // Width amount %
var idHght = charIDToTypeID( "Hght" );
var idPrc = charIDToTypeID( "#Prc" );
desc2.putUnitDouble( idHght, idPrc, -88.215838 ); // Height amount %
var idSkew = charIDToTypeID( "Skew" );
var desc4 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idHrzn = charIDToTypeID( "Hrzn" );
var idAng = charIDToTypeID( "#Ang" );
desc4.putUnitDouble( idHrzn, idAng, 0.033079 ); //skew horizontal amount
var idVrtc = charIDToTypeID( "Vrtc" );
var idAng = charIDToTypeID( "#Ang" );
desc4.putUnitDouble( idVrtc, idAng, 0.000000 ); // skew vertical amount
var idPnt = charIDToTypeID( "Pnt " );
desc2.putObject( idSkew, idPnt, desc4 );
var idAngl = charIDToTypeID( "Angl" );
var idAng = charIDToTypeID( "#Ang" );
desc2.putUnitDouble( idAngl, idAng, -170.957285 ); // rotational angle amount= 9.042715 
executeAction( idTrnf, desc2, DialogModes.NO );
```

Most parameters are in the same order as they appear in the Photoshop menus. It's a process of eliminating them to work out what each one does.

Comment: yes, it come from ScriptListener.8li, but I want to know how to generate code like funciton getLBounds(), more exactly, how to call the function executeActionGet? thx!

Comment: The scriptlistener will on generate code. You have to parameterize it and put in a function yourself. read Using ScriptListener to find event IDs and class IDs page 81 of [Photoshop Scripting Guide](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-cc-scripting-guide-2015.pdf)

Comment: oh i have read it, it only gives event IDs, e.g. in the function getLBounds, executeActionGet()  gets layer's description, but it is just a guess, it is all?

Comment: after that, the property name bounds is also by guessing? or I can know it somewhere else? Thank you very much!